# Can't switch to japanese input on windows 10, it worked fine before

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I noticed a week ago that there is only russian and english keyboard layout now for me, but there used to be japanese there too. I can still see japanese in the settings, but not in the actual menu.

[Here is what I see when trying to switch language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIFbe.png)

[And this is what I see in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkNeU.png)

Comment: You say that there is no Third Option for switching to the Japanese Language, but still the Language-Switching Menu has Three Options. What is the name of the Third Option? Can you translate the Texts into the English Language so that we can understand what is going on?

Comment: It says "language options".

Comment: Weird. In our Software Installation, there is no such Menu Header. Can you try to approach this Issue the _Microsoft_ way? Can you uninstall the Japanese Language Support and then reinstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always try to remove the Japanese layout and reinstalling it, works half of the time.

in case it doesn't work you have some sort of problem with windows's keyboard interface, and you'll have to ask somebody else